# rspec-rails and factory girl block in <top (required)>': undefined method `build'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a new Rails 4 project with FactoryGirl and rSpec. In my `spec_helper.rb` I have:

```
# lots of stuff
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # more stuff
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

I also removed the `rspec/autorun` require in this file.

A simple spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  build(:user)
end
```

with a simple factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email     "somename@someplace.com"
  end
end
```

Fails with the following message.

```
`block in <top (required)>': undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x007fd46d0e3848> (NoMethodError)
```

However, if I explicitly qualify `build` in the spec like this it passes:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  FactoryGirl.build(:user)
end
```

What can I do so I don't have to add `FactoryGirl` every time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The methods passed to `config.include` are only included by RSpec within the `it`, `let`, `before` and `after` blocks, not at the top level of `describe`. Since that's where you generally need to put your setup and test logic, in practice it's not really an issue.

Comment: <sheepish look> I was transitioning from Machinist to FactoryGirl and stuck what seemed like the simplest thing possible together so I could get a read on how this worked.